# SAS - keeping observations 6 months before and after a service date

Tags: sql, date, sas

I have a health care data set in which each month a subject is enrolled they have a row of data a variable indicating the month of active enrollment. therefore if someone is enrolled for 12 months, they will have 12 rows in the set. They also have a variable for service date, giving the exact date they received a service.

I need to select the 6 consecutive months of enrollment before and the 6 consecutive months of enrollment after the service date. The specific days of the month are irrelevant. What is important is only the month and year of the service and enrollment month.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
    service_dt   MemberID   enroll_month
    11May2010       1         01Nov2009
    11May2010       1         01Dec2009
    11May2010       1         01Jan2010
    11May2010       1         01Feb2010
    11May2010       1         01Mar2010
    11May2010       1         01Apr2010
    11May2010       1         01May2010
    11May2010       1         01Jun2010
    11May2010       1         01Jul2010
    15Jun2010       2         01Jun2010
    15Jun2010       2         01Aug2010
```

So, for member 1 we see that the service was in may, so I need to select November 2009 though November 2010 IF the months are consecutive. For member 2, service was in June, but enrollment skips from June to August...July is not an enrollment month, and so I would need to throw out member 2 from my final cohort.

Comment: There are many ways to this.  What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly I am at a loss at how to attempt this...the thing that is tripping me up is the service date needing to be in the middle of the observations. I thought about using a count, but that wouldn't ensure that the months are consecutive. I thought about subtracting the enroll month from the service date, and then selecting numbers <180, but didn't think that was the most efficient route for me to take. I just think I don't know enough about different SAS data steps or functions to appropriately tackle this issue.

Comment: `intnx` or `intck` are functions you should learn; that is how you will determine # of months difference.  Otherwise, approach it as two problems: picking the records 6 months before, and picking those 6 months after; that may be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice of @Joe , and separated my data into two sets. Before the service date and after the service date. I then followed code also supplied by Joe from a previous question I asked. However, I simply modified slightly.

```
     /* This code will focus on the months before the service date.*/
     data eligibility_before2;
        set eligibility_before;
        by memberid descending monthid;
        if first.memberid then counter = 0;
        if dif(monthid) < -1 and mod(monthid, 100) ne 12 then counter = 0;
        if mod(monthid, 100) eq 12 and dif(monthid) ne -89 then counter = 0;
        counter+1;
        if counter = 6 then output;
    run;

   /*This code will focus on enrollment months after the service date*/
    data eligibility_after2;
        set eligibility_after;
        by memberid monthid;
        if first.memberid then counter = 0;
        if dif(monthid) > 1 and mod(monthid, 100) ne 1 then counter = 0;
        if mod(monthid, 100) eq 1 and dif(monthid) ne 89 then counter = 0;
        counter+1;
        if counter = 6 then output;
    run;
```

After this point simply merge the data sets back together, specifying that the memberid must occur in BOTH data sets to be included in the final set.

Answer (score 0):

You want records for the first six months after the earliest enroll month.  You can get all members that fit this criteria by doing a `join`.  Because of the SQL tag, I am assuming that you want this as a SQL statement:

```
select d.memberid
from data d join
     (select min(year(service_dt) * 12 + month(service_dt)) as enroll_ym, d.*
      from data d
     ) dym
     on d.memberid = dym.memberid and
        year(d.service_dt) * 12 + month(service_dt) between enroll_ym and enroll_ym + 5
group by d.memberid
having count(distinct month(service_dt)) = 6;
```

To get the original rows, you would join back to the original data.

Comment: I appreciate your answer...however I cannot validate that it works, as my 'join on' statement is not being recognized in SAS. I'll have to do some debugging and investigating before I can objectively decide if this answer solves my issue or not.

Comment: @Terah . . . Oops.  I had left an extra `join` in the query.  It is now removed.

Comment: Well, perhaps it was a mistake for me to request SQL. I do not know much about SQL, but have heard it is relatively easy if you know SAS coding. I have tried your approach, but I still can't get it to work. I'm sure it is my own shortcomings and I do apologize. I get an error message telling me work.data.data does not exist. I don't know where this is coming from since I don't have anything in the code referencing a work.data.data...I replaced all references to the data set in your code with my own data set, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I apologize for wasting your time on this :(